# Why scala class need to explicitly extend AnyRef

Tags: scala

I saw some code from a library:

```
trait A extends scala.AnyRef
trait B extends scala.AnyRef with A
```

Why does `A` need to explicitly extend `AnyRef`? Aren't all classes implicitly derived from `AnyRef` already?

Why does `B` need to extend `AnyRef` even though `A` already did this? What's the difference to change above code to:

```
trait A
trait B extends A
```

Comment: a well known library. don't want to mention the name here.

Comment: Why not? Some context might help figure out if there's any reason this.

Comment: There is no difference.  `extends Any` _is_ different, as it is a signal that the trait should be compatible with value classes.

Comment: Older versions of scala may distinguish between AnyRef and ScalaObject. I suppose that extending directly AnyRef preventing from extending ScalaObject. But I don't have access to the older versions to test my hypothesis.

Comment: Are you looking at decompiled source?  It may not be in the original code but it may show up e.g. when trying to navigate into a library in intellij or eclipse when no source is available.

Answer (score 9):

I'd say no difference whatsoever.

From the [scala documentation](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/unified-types.html)

> User-defined classes define reference types by default; i.e. they always (indirectly) subclass `scala.AnyRef`.

To further prove the point

```
scala> trait A
defined trait A

scala> trait B extends A
defined trait B

scala> val a = new A { }
a: A = $anon$1@2d6d8735

scala> val b = new B { }
b: B = $anon$1@47f37ef1

scala> a.isInstanceOf[AnyRef]
res4: Boolean = true

scala> b.isInstanceOf[AnyRef]
res7: Boolean = true
```

Answer (score 2):

You do not have to explicitly extend AnyRef.
AnyRef is the equivalent of Java's Object in Scala.
By creating an instance of a class, that instance will be extending AnyRef implicitly regardless of if it was explicitly mentioned in one of its super classes or not.

The following code just creates an anonymous class, thus it also extends AnyRef implicitly:

```
trait A
val a = new A { }
```

**Here is the explanation from scala-lang.org:**

> The superclass of all classes scala.Any has two direct subclasses scala.AnyVal and scala.AnyRef representing two different class worlds: value classes and reference classes. All value classes are predefined; they correspond to the primitive types of Java-like languages. All other classes define reference types. User-defined classes define reference types by default; i.e. they always (indirectly) subclass scala.AnyRef. Every user-defined class in Scala implicitly extends the trait scala.ScalaObject. Classes from the infrastructure on which Scala is running (e.g. the Java runtime environment) do not extend scala.ScalaObject. If Scala is used in the context of a Java runtime environment, then scala.AnyRef corresponds to java.lang.Object. Please note that the diagram above also shows implicit conversions called views between the value classs. Here is an example that demonstrates that both numbers, characters, boolean values, and functions are objects just like every other object:

http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/unified-types.html

Since Scala 2.10 you can also extend AnyVal. From scala-lang.org:

> AnyVal is the root class of all value types, which describe values not implemented as objects in the underlying host system.
>   Prior to Scala 2.10, AnyVal was a sealed trait. Beginning with Scala 2.10, however, it is possible to define a subclass of AnyVal called a user-defined value class which is treated specially by the compiler. Properly-defined user value classes provide a way to improve performance on user-defined types by avoiding object allocation at runtime, and by replacing virtual method invocations with static method invocations.

Comment: It might be worth adding info about `AnyVal` added later, which makes the  part "they always ... subclass scala.AnyRef" not exactly true.

Comment: By checking with isInstanceOf you will see that user created classes that extend AnyVal actually also extend AnyRef. It's weird but that's how it was implemented.

Comment: That's not precisely true. It just happens that `isInstanceOf` entirely relies on the jvm runtime type, and as such leaks information that is pretty much an implementation detail. When you call `isInstanceOf` on some value class instance, the value is first boxed, and naturally this boxed instance extends `Object` (aka `AnyRef`). You can call it a bug, a surprising behaviour, or a blatant case of [leaky abstraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaky_abstraction). But you can't say that an `AnyVal` is an `AnyRef`.